# $4ax^3 + 3bx^2 + 2cx= a + b+ c$ has at least one root in $(0,1)$

Tags: calculus

I've been assigned the following problem: show that $$4ax^3 + 3bx^2 + 2cx= a + b+ c$$ has at least one root between $0$ and $1$. How can I do that? I was trying to use Bolzano's theorem, but it didn’t work out well. What else can I try?

Comment: What are $a$, $b$ and $c$? Are there any assumptions on them?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let us consider the function 
$$f(x)=ax^4+bx^3+cx^2 - (a+b+c)x.$$

> We have that $f(0)=f(1)=0$. Hence, by Rolle’s theorem, there is a point  $x_0 \in (0, 1)$ such that $f’(x_0)=0$. In other words, $x_0$ is a root of $4ax^3 + 3bx^2 + 2cx= a + b+ c$.